# Can't select edges after dissolving and using loop cut tool

Tags: modeling, mesh

I used the loop cut tool around the side of this model and then dissolved the edges because I thought it would save on file size and rendering and now I cannot select the area marked with the darker orange lines at all. Is this retrievable or will I have to start again?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that those edges that appear orange cannot be selected? Or the faces that share those edges?

Comment: Sorry, just realized the question title says "faces"

Comment: It seems you should remove doubles in that mesh (with all selected `W` > *Remove Doubles*), try to switch **Selection mode** to *Faces* and select faces after that.

Comment: It looks like those dark orange edges may be a part of another object that was also selected when you went into edit mode.  You could also have inadvertently pressed [P] with that geometry selected.  Try exiting edit mode and hitting [Ctrl]+[J].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those dark orange edges are on a separate object which is selected outside of edit mode.  Either you had both objects selected when you went into edit mode, or you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + xlicked it while in edit mode, or (more likely) you inadvertently disconnected it by hitting <kbd>P</kbd> with that geometry selected.

Either way, you can fix this by exiting edit mode and joining the two back together again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (with both still selected).

If you need to reconnect the edges, select the vertices in pairs and merge them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.  (Selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd> and hitting <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* may also work to reconnect at least some of the geometry.)

Comment: that worked! cheers mate

Comment: oo. when i say it worked I can select them again and they appear as nGon but when I select the subdiv surface it makes them into seperate pools with holes around the outside

Comment: @DaveGoateze  You can merge the vertices along the edge by selecting them in pairs and hitting [Alt]+[M].  Or try selecting all ([A]) and hitting [W] > *Remove Doubles*.

Comment: @DaveGoateze  Glad I could help!  To mark that this answer has solved your problem and take this off the unanswered list you can click the [green checkmark](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) under the voting buttons.

Comment: sorry I cant see a green checkmark or a voting button

Comment: @DaveGoateze It looks [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yblY8.png).

Comment: got it cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

I have had a mesh become corrupted so that certain functions/actions cannot be performed on it.
If it seems your mesh is corrupted, which it may be, try various creative ways to trick the software, such as:

1. Export an .OBJ, and then open/import the file into a new blender project.
2. Use a mirror modifier or array modifier to create a pseudo-copy. Apply the modifier and then delete the original, leaving one of the copies. (Mirror back if needed).

   3. If these don't work, you still don't need to start completely over. You can quickly rebuild it using the corrupt mesh as like a template that you can snap the points of the new mesh to the points on the old mesh.

Comment: Nice one cheers yeah it was totally corrupted after I dissolved the faces marked by the orange border. I did a loop cut to extrude the two pieces at the bottom and thought I should disolve what i didn't need to extrude.They are all totally untouchable now, I can't even delete them. I have already rebuilt what I have in the picture, thanks for your help i will be careful with the loop cut tool